# StartDate and EndDate

Tags: perl

Can you please help me with this piece of code

#### Perl BAT command

```
perl MCLoader_DSS.pl -sSERVERNAME -u** -p** -c321 -i511359 -H1 -C1 -a2015-07-28 > a.txt
pause
```

#### Code in the file

```
    $mStartDate = $endDate;
    $mStartDate =~ s/\-//g;
    $mStartDate =~ s/\'//g;

    $mEndDate = $endDate;
    $mEndDate =~ s/\'//g;

    ($yy, $mm, $dd) = Add_Delta_Days(split('-', $mEndDate), 1);
    $mEndDate = sprintf ('%4d-%02d-%02d', $yy, $mm, $dd);
    $mEndDate = "'".$mEndDate ."'";
```

The output I get in the text file is

```
@StartDate = '2015-07-29', @EndDate = '2015-07-30'
```

which actually doesnt match with the date I passed

I wish to achieve `@Startdate = [The date I pass]` i.e. : a2015-07-28 and the `@EndDate = [Should add +1 to its date]`

And how can I explicitly pass both the dates?

Comment: Can you give some more explicit sample input? And be more specific about what your 'start' and 'end' date are set to, because what you've quoted isn't valid.

Comment: HI @Sobrique we have a **Perl Engine** setup and that's what passes the data to run the perl file
perl MCLoader_DSS.pl [This is the perl file being called]-sSERVERNAME [Server to run on] -u** [Username] -p** [Password]-c321[Predicate Data] -i511359[Predicate data] -H1 [HTMl format output] -C1 [CSV output] -a2015-07-28 [Startdate] > a.txt
pause

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're making this all far harder than it needs to be. [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) has been included with Perl since 2007.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $format = '%Y-%m-%d';

my $start_date = Time::Piece->strptime('2015-07-28', $format);
my $end_date   = $start_date + ONE_DAY;

say $start_date->strftime($format);
say $end_date->strftime($format);
```